# Sync xmlhttprequest is stuck in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, bots

I create some bot for my purposes. He send sync xmlhttprequest to resourse. Its working fine, but sometimes request is "stuck" and bot stop working (nothing happns in console window). I have reduced the number of requests to one in 7! minutes, but this happens still. Restarting bot solving the problem for some time. If i use async request i get error "the reqest was already sended" sometimes and bot stop working.
Unfulfilled requests accumulate in visual studio code explorer, as I understand it (I attach a screenshot).

[image: Unfulfilled requests accumulate in visual studio code explorer, as I understand it]

Comment: your previous request hasn't finished before you make the next request, thats your issue

Comment: I give 7 minutete fot this... How can i check o resend request, or handle error? In my code i waiting for readyState == 4 and status == 200.

Comment: I suggest you create a "pool" and "queue" for your requests, then run the queue first, and then wait for a request to complete or error, if it errors, redo the request, else go to the next request, also setup a max retry counter.

Comment: this will solve your issue, also you will only have 1 request running at a time.

Comment: combine this with promises, pool list and queue. create your own JS library to handle this

Comment: I didn't provide enough information. My bot consists of 7 small bots (so far I have done so) that send information to one resource every 7 minutes. Can this cause problems?

Comment: yes.........................